# Cambiar un Date Format MYSQL

Tags: mysql

acaban de meter la pata en mi base de datos, y me han cambiado un formato de fechas
Estoy tratando de recuperar dicho formato, pero no se como simplemente actualizarlos
Ya recupere los datos, pero las fechas debo corregir el formato.

El mayor problema, es que no es una columna de fecha, sino un varchar que se llama fecha y debo trabajar sobre eso.

El formato que quiero obtener es este -> "YYYY-mm-dd" 
El formato en el logre recuperar los datos está en -> "dd-mm-YYYY"
Ahora mismo estoy tratando esto:

```
UPDATE tabla SET fecha = DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%y-%m-%d")
```

Pero esto me está truncando los datos y arruinando lo que he podido recuperar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba primero convirtinedo la cadena en una fecha (`date`) con la función `STR_TO_DATE` y luego volviendo a convertir dicha fecha en una cadena (con la función `DATE_FORMAT`) con el formato deseado:

```
UPDATE tabla 
SET fecha =  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Antes de ejecutar el `UPDATE` te recomiendo que lo pruebes con una query para corroborar que es el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Justo estaba en eso, pensé lo mismo que explicaste, y busque como usar el STR_TO_DATE, pero me faltaba agregar el formato en STR_TO_DATE. Con tu explicacion he terminado de corregir, muchas gracias !!

Comment: pd. en 4 min acepto la respuesta, no me deja antes

Comment: De nada @Excorpion! Me alegra haberte ayudado.